# how could I wait until the method is finished?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a datagrid and two comboboxes. The data grid contains documents, the first combobox persons that can be owned the documents and the second combobox has the phone numbers of the person selected in the first combobox.

The first combobox has always all the persons that can own documents.

If I don't select a document in the datagrid but I select a person in the first combobox, I want to fill the second combobox with all the phone numbers of the selected person. Bu I don't want to select any phone number.

If I select a document in the datagrid, I want to select the owner of the document in the first combobox and the phone number that is set in the document.

I am using an async method to get the data (phone numbers) each time I select a owner of the document. The code is this:

```
public Documents SelectedDocumentInDataGrid;
public Persons SelectedPersonInComboBox;
public PhoneNumbers SelectedPhoneNumberInComboBox;
```

This are properties that I am using to bind my view with my view model. Just I show this to sumplify code.

Now, the code when I select a document in my datagrid:

```
public ObservableCollection<Documents> Documents
{
    get { return _documents; }
    set
    {
        _documents = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Documents");
    }
}

public Documents DocumentsSelectedItem
{
    get { return _documentsSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _documentsSelectedItem = value;
        documentsSelectionChanged();
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("DocumentsSelectedItem");
    }
}


public ObservableCollection<Persons> Owners;
{
    get { return _owners; }
    set
    {
        _owners = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Owners");
    }
}

public Persons OwnersSelectedItem
{
    get { return _ownersSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _ownersSelectedItem = value;
        ownersSelectionChanged();
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("OwnersSelectedItem");
    }
}


public ObservableCollection<PhonesNumbers> PhoneNumbers
{
    get { return _phoneNumbers; }
    set
    {
        _phoneNumbers = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PhoneNumbers");
    }
}

public PhonesNumbers PhoneNumbersSelectedItem
{
    get { return _phoneNumbersSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _phoneNumbersSelectedItem = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PhoneNumbersSelectedItem");
    }
}




private void documentsSelectionChanged()
{
    OwnersSelectedItem = Owners.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDPerson == DocumentsSelectedItem?.IDOwner);
    PhoneNumbersSelectedItem = PhoneNumbersSelectedItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDPhoneNumber == DocumentsSelectedItem?.)IDPhoneNumber);
}


private async Task ownersSelectionChanged()
{
    await myRepository.getPhonesNumbersAsync(OwnersSelectedItem?.IDPerson)
        .ContinueWith((myTask) =>
        {
            PhonesNumbers = new ObservableCollection<PhonesNumbers>(await myTask);
        },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

The problem is that the async method is called in the set property of OwnersSelectedItem.

The reason is that everytime that I select an owner, I want to fill the combobox of the phone numbers. And if I select a document, I have to select the owner and the phone number, so I can reuse the code of the set of selected owner.

In this way in the method that is called when I select the document, I just have to select the owner and then select the phone number.

The problem is that in the set of the owner, I can use await, beceause it is a property, so when I select a document and set the owner, it doens't wait to finish the get the phone numbers, so in the next line, when I try to select the phone number, I don't have the phone number yet so the combobox is empty.

I would like to know if there is some way to can wait to finish the set of owner finish bafore pass to the line to select the phone number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an `async` property in C#, so you cannot `await` a method in a property getter or setter.

But you could remove the setter from the property (which disallows setting it directly), and instead have an `async` method to set it.

```
public Persons OwnersSelectedItem
{
    get { return _ownersSelectedItem; }
}

public async Task SetOwnersSelectedItem(Person newPerson)
{
    _ownersSelectedItem = newPerson;
    await ownersSelectionChanged();
    base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("OwnersSelectedItem");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One interesting thing about your code is that you mix `await` and `ContinueWith`:

```
private async Task ownersSelectionChanged()
{
    await myRepository.getPhonesNumbersAsync(OwnersSelectedItem?.IDPerson)
        .ContinueWith((myTask) =>
        {
            PhonesNumbers = new ObservableCollection<PhonesNumbers>(await myTask);
        },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

There is no need to do that - the purpose of `await` is to resume your code when the task is complete. So something like this should be fine:

```
private async Task ownersSelectionChanged()
{
    var phoneNumbers = await myRepository.getPhonesNumbersAsync(OwnersSelectedItem?.IDPerson);

    PhonesNumbers = new ObservableCollection<PhonesNumbers>(phoneNumbers);

    PhoneNumbersSelectedItem = PhonesNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDPhoneNumber == DocumentsSelectedItem?.)IDPhoneNumber)
}
```

Note that you can do the selecting of a default phone number right after you get the list here. This seems to be the right place to do it; it will happen automatically when the user selects a different owner.

(NB. I've made it search in `PhonesNumbers` rather than `PhoneNumbersSelectedItem` as that makes more sense?)

Comment: Yes, you are right about your comment, I wrote the a bit by memory and I make a mistake.
But the question here is that in my code, I think it is better don't do the selection of the items in the method that select the document, not in the code that set the owner. In hits case, if first I select the owner and later try to find the phone number, I can't finde because the code continue, because I can await the set of the owner (OwnersSelectedItem). I would like to know if there is some way to await when I use async methods in a set of a property.